# Constructing a point D on AB such that PD is perpendicular to AB

Tags: geometry

I need to write the steps of construction from this exercise.

> Construct a line segment $AB$, and a point $P$, not on $AB$. Use the theorem on the previous page or one of its alternative statements to construct a point $D$ on $AB$ such that $PD ⊥ AB$. Write down your steps of construction, and explain how you used the theorem to do the construction.

This is the previous theorem: In an isosceles triangle, the median to the base is the perpendicular bisector (of the base) and also the angle bisector for the angle opposite to the base.

So far I have learned how to create an equilateral triangle with side $AB$ by using the intersections of circle $(A,AB)$ and circle $(B,BA)$.

I am unsure how to start this. I think I need to somehow create a isosceles triangle that would be triangle $PAB$ but not sure how to construct it?

Comment: What is "the theorem on the previous page?" Is that the isosceles triangle fact? Please [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4021058/edit) to explain clearly what your allowed tools are and what you have tried. In general it would NOT be the case that $\triangle PAB$ would be isosceles.

Comment: Joffan- I made changes to be clear that the isosceles triangle fact is the theorem from the previous page.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a circle centered on $P$ that passes through $A$ (that is, radius $|PA|$)${}^*$. Extend line $AB$ if necessary to have two points of intersection with the circle; $A$ and a new point $F$. These are equidistant from $P$ and so $\triangle APF$ is isosceles, with $AF$ the base.

Now bisect the line $AF$ (you know how to do this?) at $D$ and by the theorem $PD$ is the perpendicular bisector of $\triangle APF$ and so $D$ is the point as required.

[image]

---

$*\;$ For practical purposes, if $\angle PAB$ appears to be close to a right angle, draw the initial $P$-centered circle through $B$ instead and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Construct circle such as P is center and PA is radius. P,A, and other inserction of circle and line form isosceles triangle

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Draw a line $\mathcal{L}_a$ through the points $A$ and $B$.
2. Draw a line $\mathcal{L}_p$ through the points $A$ and $P$.
3. Draw a circle $\mathcal{C}_a(A,|AP|)$.
4. Draw a circle $\mathcal{C}_p(P,|AP|)$.
   Call the intersection points of
   $\mathcal{C}_a$ and $\mathcal{C}_p$ as $E$ and $F$.
5. Draw a line $\mathcal{L}_o$ through the points $E$ and $F$.
   Let $O=\mathcal{L}_a\cap\mathcal{L}_o$.
6. Draw a circle $\mathcal{C}_o(O,|AO|)$.
   The sought point is $D=\mathcal{C}_o\cap\mathcal{L}_a$.

Steps 2-5 are used to find the midpoint $O$ of $AP$, so
that $|OA|=|OP|=\tfrac12|AP|$ is the diameter of $\mathcal{C}_o$.